# appent text to input field

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to append a text to input field?

So lets say instead of:

```
<input type="text" id="val" name="val" value="http://" style="width: 140px;" />
```

with "`http://`" already written, have a "`http://`" added automatically when someone types an address, and if someone types full url "`http://www.****.com`" the http should not be added so it's not doubled.

Any one has any ideas? I can't use php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add the `http://` if it is missing?

```
var input = document.getElementById('val').value;

if (input.search('http://') === -1) {
    input = 'http://' + input;
}
```

edit: if you need to allow https also, change the search to a regex:

```
if (input.search(/https?:\/\//) === -1) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/Bt67X/

Comment: Great stuff, exacly what I needed with little change. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great answer as this is I'm having second though on it. What if I wanted to put https in there?

Answer (score 0):

***Append:***

`document.getElementById('val').value += "http://www.google.co.uk";`

***Remove Duplicate:***`

`document.getElementById('val').value.replace("http://http://","http://");`

This way, if they did type `http://` twice, it would just remove it.

Comment: Your `document.getElementById` ID strings need to have closing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using a scripting framework, e.g. jQuery (http://jquery.com) to access the input field.

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5BLrU/

Here is the JS code for reference

```
$(function() {
    $("#some-form").submit(function(){
        var $val = $("#val");
        var url = $val.val();
        if (!/^http:\/\/.+/.test(url)) {
            $val.val("http://" + url);
        }
        // remove this to submit the form!
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example assumes the ID of the target element is **val**.

```
// Store current element
var elem = document.getElementById('val'),
    // Store current value
    currentValue = elem.value;

// Prepend something if not present
if (currentValue.match(/^http:\/\//) == false) {
    currentValue = 'http://' + currentValue;
}

// Re-assign
elem.value = currentValue;
```